# Select2 JQuery onChange disable Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-community

I am using select2 JQuery in my lightning component and i have to disable button on this component once all values are selected. below is sample Code.

## MarkUp

```
    <aura:component controller="accountDataController" >

        <ltng:require styles="{! $Resource.select2 + '/select2-4.0.3/dist/css/select2.min.css'}" 
          scripts="{!join(',', 
            $Resource.jquery224 ,  
            $Resource.select2 + '/select2-4.0.3/dist/js/select2.js')
          }" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>

        <aura:attribute name="picklistOptsList" type="String[]"/>

        <aura:attribute name="disableButton" type="Boolean" />

       <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
        <!-- picklistOptsList comes from Apex Controller-->
        <div class="slds-m-around--medium slds-form--compound" >  
            <div class="form-element__group">
                <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">  
                        <label for="picklist">Role</label> <br/>
                        <select style="width:100%" id="picklist" class="select2Class" multiple="multiple">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.picklistOptsList}" var="opts">
                                <option value="{!opts}"> {!opts} </option>
                            </aura:iteration>     
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <lightning:button label="Back" onclick="{!c.goBack}" />
            <lightning:button label="DisableButton" onclick="{!c.contactCreate}" disabled="{!v.disableButton}"/> <!-- Needs to disable this button, once all values are selected.

        </div>    
    </aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
    ({
        scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
            console.log('load successfully');

           // active/call select2 plugin function after load jQuery and select2 plugin successfully    
           $(".select2Class").select2({
               placeholder: "Select Multiple values"
           });
        },

        doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

            console.log("Enter Address Data Controller");

            //initialize picklistOptsList using Apex controller
        },

        goBack : function(component, event, helper) {
            //Back Functionality to other componentent      
        }
    })
```

How can i disable the button once all values are selected. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily in Lightning, just add an onchange handler:

```
<select style="width:100%" 
        id="picklist"
        aura:id="picklist"
        onchange="{!c.updateButtonState}"
        class="select2Class" 
        multiple="multiple">
```

---

```
updateButtonState: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Get the select options
    let items = component.find("picklist").getElement().options;
    // Set to disabled when all options selected
    component.set("v.disableButton", Array.prototype.every.call(items, option => option.selected));
    // NOTE: This code also re-enables button when one item is deselected.
    // If not desirable, you will need to slightly modify this code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with select2 plugins loaded in the component, onchange event is not firing. You can use aura:method and call this method from parent component. This approach works for me with select2 inside aura component.